# Date-fns RangeError: Invalid time value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, vue.js, timestamp, date-fns

Hi I want to convert the mongo db created_at timestamp to when It says ... minutes/hours ago using the [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) library. The function is called `formatDistanceToNow` which returns time since the date time provided. I'm using Vue for front end but can't seem to get it working.

```html
<template>
    <div class="feed">
      <div v-for="post in feed" :key="post.id" class="post">
        <h3>{{ post.name }}</h3>
        <p>{{ post.timestamp }}</p> // return 2021-06-12T12:59:57.337Z
        <p>{{ Date(post.timestamp) }}</p> // return Mon Jun 14 2021 16:02:22 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
        <!-- <p>{{ formatDate(post.timestamp) }}</p> -->
        <!-- <p>{{ formatDate(Date(post.timestamp)) }}</p> -->
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import { formatDistanceToNow } from 'date-fns'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['feed']),
    formatDate(timestamp){
      return formatDistanceToNow(timestamp)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The 2 commented lines of code is what I've tried, but keep getting the following error

> Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Invalid time value

Comment: Your `feed` variable is fetched in an async way, right? What if you try `v-if="feed.length` on the `p` tag with `formatDate(post.timestamp)`?

Comment: Hi I'm actually using dummy data for the feed. Storing in a string => timestamp: '2021-06-12T12:59:57.337Z'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass an argument to a computed function, so here you'll need to use a `method`. Also, the time format is indeed not okay as shown in the documentation page: https://date-fns.org/v2.22.1/docs/formatDistanceToNow

`2021-06-12T12:59:57.337Z` is not the same as `Sat Jun 12 2021 14:59:57 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)` (in my timezone).
To go from one to another, use `new Date("2021-06-12T12:59:57.337Z")`

The final code is looking something like this

```html
<template>
  <div>
    format: {{ formatDate(test) }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    test: '2021-06-12T12:59:57.337Z',
  },
  methods: {
    formatDate(timestamp) {
      return formatDistanceToNow(new Date(timestamp))
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This helped me fix the issue:

```
if (isNaN(newValue.getMonth())) return;
onChange(format(newValue, 'LLLL dd, yyyy', { locale: ru }));
```

Comment: Orkhan Rahimli, this does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)

Answer (score 0):

In place of `methods`, you can use `filters` as follows;

```
<template>
 <div class="feed">
  <div v-for="post in feed" :key="post.id" class="post">
    <h3>{{ post.name }}</h3>
    <p>{{ post.timestamp | formatDate }}</p> <!-- filter here -->
  </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapState } from 'vuex'
  import { formatDistanceToNow } from 'date-fns'

  export default {
   filters: {
    formatDate(timestamp){
     if (!timestamp) return; // or return any placeholder
     return formatDistanceToNow(timestamp);
    }
   }
  }
 </script>
```