# calling new Date variable in formatWithOptions results in RangeError: Invalid time value

Tags: javascript, date-fns, crocks

I want to display the date for each entry (date, text, question, answer) in a json database within a lit element in a js module.

Relevant code:

```
import { formatWithOptions } from "date-fns/fp";
import compose from "crocks/helpers/compose";

...

const newDate = (x) => new Date(x);


const formatDateWithOptions = formatWithOptions(
  {
    awareOfUnicodeTokens: true,
  },
  "d MMMM, yyyy, h:mm a"
);

const prettyDate = compose(formatDateWithOptions, newDate); // this is registering as an invalid date
```

When `${prettyDate(date)}` is called inside a lit element, it throws

```
RangeError: Invalid time value.
```

The date format for `(date)` inside the json db is valid. Example: `"2021-12-24T21:06:06.773Z"`

According to [the date-fns docs](https://date-fns.org/v2.27.0/docs/fp/formatWithOptions), `formatWithOptions()` should be fine to call with `"d MMMM, yyyy, h:mm a"`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67972820/date-fns-rangeerror-invalid-time-value) deals with the same error, but is using a different function (formatDistanceToNow). Where am I going wrong with my variables?

Comment: You haven't shown what `date` is in `${prettyDate(date)}`, but clearly it's not in a format that the `Date` constructor can parse.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just clarified, (date) is in standard format ie "2021-12-24T21:00:47.217Z"

Comment: That's strange, because "Invalid time value" pretty clearly says that the `Date` object's time value (the underlying milliseconds-since-the-Epoch) is invalid (for instance, `NaN`), which happens when you ask `new Date` to parse something it doesn't understand. I suggest reformatting `newDate` to something like `const newDate = (x) => { const dt = new Date(x); return dt; };` and putting a breakpoint on the `return dt;` statement with the condition `isNaN(+dt);`. When the breakpoint trips, look at what `x` is. I suspect you'll find that it's not the format you're expecting. Good luck!