# Correct Date format in formatWithOptions results in Range Error: Invalid time value

Tags: javascript, date-fns, crocks

I want to display the date for each entry (date, text, question, answer) in a json database within a lit element in a js module. The date format for (date) inside the json db is valid ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript)). Example: `"2021-12-24T21:06:06.773Z"`

Relevant code:

```
import { formatWithOptions } from "date-fns/fp";
import compose from "crocks/helpers/compose";

...

const newDate = (x) => new Date(x);


const formatDateWithOptions = formatWithOptions(
  {
    awareOfUnicodeTokens: true,
  },
  "d MMMM, yyyy, h:mm a"
);

const prettyDate = compose(formatDateWithOptions, newDate); // this is registering as an invalid date
```

When `${prettyDate(date)}` is called inside a lit element, it throws

```
RangeError: Invalid time value.
```

According to [the date-fns docs](https://date-fns.org/v2.27.0/docs/fp/formatWithOptions), `formatWithOptions()` should be fine to call with `"d MMMM, yyyy, h:mm a"`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67972820/date-fns-rangeerror-invalid-time-value) deals with the same error, but is using a different function (`formatDistanceToNow`). Where am I going wrong with my variables?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will generate an invalid date if `x` is undefined.

```
const newDate = (x) => new Date(x);
```

also, don't forget that you need to execute the compose function to provide an input to the `newDate` function.

The code below should work:

```
const MY_DATE_STR = "2021-12-24T21:06:06.773Z";

const newDate = x => {
  if (x === undefined) { return new Date(); }
  return new Date(x);
}

const formatDateWithOptions = formatWithOptions(
  {
    awareOfUnicodeTokens: true,
  },
  "d MMMM, yyyy, h:mm a"
  );

const prettyDate = compose(formatDateWithOptions, newDate)(MY_DATE_STR);

console.log(prettyDate); // 24 December, 2021, 1:06 PM
```